# CPU Burst or I/O Burst

Tags: process, io, scheduling

If a process that currently is being executed faces an I/O Burst, will the next available process gain the CPU burst or will the processor wait until the I/O Burst of the first process finishes to continue executing the first process.

Also does this get affected by whether an algorithm is preemptive or non-preemptive?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes. When a CPU bound task becomes I/O constrained then the OS will reschedule the task until it is ready to perform more CPU work. That means that other processes (that have work for the CPU to do) will get the time on the CPU instead.

For a longer answer, this was the first time I had come across these particular terms. I could only find a handful of pages mentioning it and it appears to be an optimisation strategy rather than a physical CPU or operating system feature. It's not a "burst phase" in the operating system or CPU that can be shared between processes, it is simply that a process "bursts" when it has work to do in one domain or the other. By optimising your workflow to do one more than the other, and storing up work for the other, you can make those "bursts" of work more effective.

As such whether the operating system is preemptive or non-preemptive is irrelevant. It just knows that the process is stuck waiting or is ready to go and will schedule it accordingly. If a process was doing calculations and suddenly tries to read a file then it will stall and be rescheduled when the data is available.

The only reason these "bursts" are relevant is to make sure you are using your operating system scheduled time slices effectively. If you have a lot of I/O interspersed in your CPU bound task then you will stall and potentially loose a portion of your scheduled time waiting for those I/O operations. If you batch up I/O into "bursts" then your process makes better use of its time on the CPU and gets the full time slice.